# What's the recommended way of handling complexly composed POD(plain-old-data in OO) in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm a Haskell newbie.

In statically typed OO languages (for instance, Java), all complex data structures are presented as class and instances. An object can have many attributes (fields). And another object can be a value of the field. Those fields can be accessed with their names, and statically typed by class. Finally, those objects construct huge graph of object which linked each other. Most program uses data graph like this.

How can I archive these functionality in Haskell?

Comment: [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com) and [RWH](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read) are always highly recommended reads. I will not tire of recommending them to self-proclaimed Haskell newbies such as yourself. Both are excellent at helping you think functionally.

Comment: @Dan Thanks for links. I bookmarked them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haskell has algebraic data types, which can describe structures or unions of structures such that something of a given type can hold one of a number of different sets of fields. These fields can set and accessed both positionally or via names with record syntax.

See here: http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses

Comment: Thanks. The Record is jut a syntactic sugar! But it's sad the commas looks ugly among beautiful Haskell syntax :)

Comment: Haskell record syntax is a quick-n-easy way to obtain all of the features that Eonil described. Rather than the Java-like `object.getAttr()`, in Haskell you would simply do `attrName object`, since record syntax defines getter functions automatically.

Answer (score 6):

If you really do have data without behavior, this maps nicely to a Haskell record:

```
data Person = Person { name    :: String
                     , address :: String }
            deriving (Eq, Read, Show)

data Department = Management | Accounting | IT | Programming
                deriving (Eq, Read, Show)

data Employee = Employee   { identity   :: Person
                           , idNumber   :: Int
                           , department :: Department }
              | Contractor { identity :: Person
                           , company  :: String }
              deriving (Eq, Read, Show)
```

This says that a `Person` is a `Person` who has a `name` and `address` (both `String`s); a `Department` is either `Management`, `Accounting`, `IT`, or `Programming`; and an `Employee` is either an `Employee` who has an `identity` (a `Person`), an `idNumber` (an `Int`), and a `department` (a `Department`), or is a `Contractor` who has an `identity` (a `Person`) and a `company` (a `String`).  The `deriving (Eq, Read, Show)` lines enable you to compare these objects for equality, read them in, and convert them to strings.

In general, a Haskell data type is a combination of unions (also called *sums*) and tuples (also called *products*).<sup>1</sup>  The `|`s denote choice (a union): an `Employee` is *either* an `Employee` or a `Contractor`, a `Department` is one of four things, etc.  In general, tuples are written something like the following:

```
data Process = Process String Int
```

This says that `Process` (in addition to being a type name) is a data constructor with type `String -> Int -> Process`.  Thus, for instance, `Process "init" 1`, or `Process "ls" 57300`.  A `Process` has to have *both* a `String` and an `Int` to exist.  The record notation used above is just syntactic sugar for these products; I could also have written `data Person = Person String String`, and then defined

```
name :: Person -> String
name (Person n _) = n

address :: Person -> String
address (Person _ a) = a
```

Record notation, however, can be nice for complex data structures.

Also note that you can parametrize a Haskell type over other types; for instance, a three-dimensional point could be `data Point3 a = Point3 a a a`.  This means that `Point3 :: a -> a -> a -> Point3 a`, so that one could write `Point3 (3 :: Int) (4 :: Int) (5 :: Int)` to get a `Point3 Int`, or `Point3 (1.1 :: Double) (2.2 :: Double) (3.3 :: Double)` to get a `Point3 Double`.  (Or `Point3 1 2 3` to get a `Num a => Point3 a`, if you've seen type classes and overloaded numeric literals.)

This is what you need to represent a data graph.  However, take note: one problem for people transitioning from imperative languages to functional ones—or, really, between any two different paradigms (C to Python, Prolog to Ruby, Erlang to Java, whatever)—is to continue to try to solve problems the old way.  The solution you're trying to model *may* not be constructed in a way amenable to easy functional programming techniques, even if the problem is.  For instance, in Haskell, thinking about types is very important, in a way that's different from, say, Java.  At the same time, implementing behaviors for those types is done very differently: higher-order functions capture some of the abstractions you've seen in Java, but also some which aren't easily expressible (`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`, `filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`, and `foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b` come to mind).  So keep your options open, and consider addressing your problems in a functional way.  Of course, maybe you are, in which case, full steam ahead.  But do keep this in mind as you explore a new language.  And have fun :-)

---

**1:** And recursion: you can represent a binary tree, for instance, with `data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a)`.

Comment: Thanks. A lot helpful answer. Isn't Data-graph a recommended way in functional style? If so, can I get a recommended way to represent complex data in functional way?

Comment: @Eonil: A data-graph absolutely can be!  (Especially since it's data without behavior.)  That part of my answer was more a general warning, since you mentioned comparing it to OO languages.  While what you're doing sounds just fine, it's always worth keeping in mind that you're learning a new paradigm, and it's very easy to fall back on the old ways.  But like I said, as far as I can tell, what you're doing is fine.

Comment: Data.Graph is only recommend for graphs that you'd have a Graph class for in OO languages. They're not recommended for modeling hierarchical data like the Company example above. Essentially you want to avoid links/cross references as much as possible and make your data a tree not a graph. If you need references consider implementing them with a "relational" structure like Data.Map rather then embedding them in the tree. In a functional language graphs are harder to traverse than trees they are also harder to maintain than maps.

Comment: @stephen: When I was referring to a data-graph, I was referring to the general concept that the collection of data in your system forms a graph structure.  You do make a good point about the `Data.Graph` module, though.